# JPanel functionality equivalent in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-layout, jpanel

I want to create different layouts based on a certain input.

The objects in the layouts in general have unknown positions will be calculated by methods and the returned result will be where they should be placed but the dimentions of the objects are known, so all shapes are standard but how many and where they should be is unkown.

In Jpanel we can just draw on grid and add mouseclicker and everything is easy but android is making it difficult.

Do you guys have any ideas how can I tackle that ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no JPanel in Android. Instead, you can use LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, ConstraintLayout, etc.
Have a look at this guide : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout

Comment: Look at my question again please.